# Can't stop Eclipse complaining about an error I already fixed

Tags: android, c++, eclipse, android-ndk

Eclipse keeps giving this error for one of my C++ files:

The type 'handroid::Thread' must implement the inherited pure virtual method 'hgame::Thread::getImplementationName'

The line it flags up is the one with the new statement here (this is in namespace handroid):

```
hgame::Thread *ThreadFactory::createThread(hgame::Runnable *r,
        const char *name)
{
    return new Thread(mJVM, r, name);
}
```

handroid::Thread is derived from hgame::Thread. The thing is I fixed the error several days ago by removing the getImplementationName method altogether. I've grepped my entire workspace, the string doesn't occur anywhere in it! But Eclipse keeps resurrecting this error message no matter how many times I try rebuilding and cleaning the project, deleting the error, restarting Eclipse etc.

Comment: Have you tried "Run C/C++ Code Analysis"? Also, check the code analysis launch settings ("Properries" -> "C/C++ General" -> "Code Analysis" -> "Launching") to make sure it's getting run.

Comment: Also a "project->clean" might be fitting if you haven't tried it already.

Comment: Code Analysis doesn't clear it. I have tried Clean several times. I think Eclipse and I have confused each other. I had already written quite a lot of code, with multiple folders to support cross-platform portability, then imported it into Eclipse to supposedly make it easier to develop the Android version. I thought I was supposed to create Source Folders, but now AFAICT from Google these seem to be Java-specific, and they just made a mess of my Project Explorer. It's probably best if I delete all the Eclipse files in it and re-import it.

Answer (score 1):

"Project -> Clean" will fix your problem.